# CloudFormation YAML - IAM policy with a statement that has a condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an IAM Policy that was created automatically when creating another resource in the AWS Console. I'm trying to add this into an existing CloudFormation stack.

The policy has the following statement, which contains a "Condition" property:

```
{
    "Sid": "DecryptSecretValue",
    "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:kms:MyRegion:MyAccountId:key/4f402c6e-9624-40a4-8d4d-c0f2efe88602"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }
}
```

How should this be structured in a CloudFormation YAML template? So far I have:

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action: kms:DecryptSecretValue
    Resource: arn:aws:kms:MyRegion:MyAccountId:key/4f402c6e-9624-40a4-8d4d-c0f2efe88602
```

But I dont know how to include the "Condition" property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For each level of your json policy you add an indentation on yaml.
So `Condition` is on the same level of `Effect`, `Resource` and `Action`.
`StringEquals` is indented from `Conditions`.
`kms:ViaService` is indented from `StringEquals`.

As `kms:ViaService` has colon (`:`) in the name, you need to add it between quotes.

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action: "kms:DecryptSecretValue"
    Resource: "arn:aws:kms:MyRegion:MyAccountId:key/4f402c6e-9624-40a4-8d4d-c0f2efe88602"
    Condition:
      StringEquals:
        "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!

Comment: Great, thanks. I was off in the wrong direction messing around with the `!Equals` function